# How to handle PBXCp Error in iOS 6

Tags: ios

I have some image files that when copied
 into the Xcode project , I get the PBXCp error and a lot of warnings saying 'Dependency Analysis Warning'.What must be the reason?

Answer (score 0):

I added each image individually to Xcode rather than adding the whole folder of images and the problem was solved.